# Translate processing to p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Could someone explain to me why this translation doesn't work?
Since I'm super new to both processing and p5.js, I keep getting error messages...

This is the processing code that I'd like to change.

```processing
Particle[] particles;
float alpha;

void setup() {
  size(900, 500);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  setParticles();
}

void draw() {
  frameRate(30);
  alpha = map(height, 0, width, 5, 35);
  fill(4, 255);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  background(0);

  loadPixels();
  for (Particle p : particles) {
    p.move();
  }
  updatePixels();
}

void setParticles() {
  particles = new Particle[10000]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { 
    float x = random(width);
    float y = random(height);
    float adj = map(y, 0, height, 255, 0);
    int c = color(60, adj, 255);
    particles[i]= new Particle(x, y, c);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  setParticles();
}

class Particle {
  float posX, posY, incr, theta;
  color  c;

  Particle(float xIn, float yIn, color cIn) {
    posX = xIn;
    posY = yIn;
    c = cIn;
  }

  public void move() {
    update();
    wrap();
    display();
  }

  void update() {
    incr +=  .008;
    theta = noise(posX * .006, posY * .008, incr) * TWO_PI;
    posX += 2 * tan(theta);
    posY += 2 * sin(theta);
  }

  void display() {
    if (posX > 0 && posX < width && posY > 0  && posY < height) {
      pixels[(int)posX + (int)posY * width] =  c;
    }
  }

  void wrap() {
    if (posX < 0) posX = width;
    if (posX > width ) posX =  0;
    if (posY < 0 ) posY = height;
    if (posY > height) posY =  0;
  }
}
```

And this is the p5.js translation which doesn't work.

```p5
var particles;
let particle  = [];
const num = 100;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(900, 500);
    background(0);
    noStroke();
    setParticles();
}

function draw() {
    frameRate(30);
    let alpha = map(height, 0, width, 5, 35);
    fill(0, alpha);
    rect(0, 0, width, height);
    loadPixels();
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) { 
    particles[i].update();
    particles[i].display();
    particles[i].wrap();
    }
    updatePixels();
}

function setParticles() {
    particles = new Array(10000);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        var x = random(width);
        var y = random(height);
        var adj = map(y, 0, height, 255, 0);
        let c = color(60, adj, 255);
        particles[i] = new Particle(x, y, c);
    }
}

function mousePressed() {
    setParticles();
}

function Particle (xln, yln, cln) {
    this.posX = xln;
    this.posY = yln;
    this.c = cln;

this.update = function() {
    this.incr += .008;
    this.theta = noise(this.posX * .006, this.posY * .008, this.incr) * TWO_PI;
    this.posX += 2 * tan(this.theta);
    this.posY += 2 * sin(this.theta);
}

this.display = function() {
    if (this.posX > 0 && this.posX < width && this.posY > 0 && this.posY < height) {
        pixels[int(this.posX) + int(this.posY) * width] = c;
    }
}

this.wrap = function() {
    if (this.posX < 0)
        this.posX = width;
    if (this.posX > width)
        this.posX = 0;
    if (this.posY < 0)
        this.posY = height;
    if (this.posY > height)
        this.posY = 0;
}
}
```

I'll be a great help if anyone with experience could help me!

Comment: What exactly are the error messages that you keep getting?

Answer (score 3):

Cool project! You're very close there were just a few things that needed tweaking.

If you plonk a `console.log(this.posX)` in the `display()` function you'll see that it's `NaN`, if you trace your steps you'll notice that it's caused by:

```js
this.theta = noise(this.posX * 0.006, this.posY * 0.008, this.incr) * TWO_PI;
this.posX += 2 * sin(this.theta);
```

The problem here being that `this.incr` wasn't defined, so adding `this.incr = 0` to the constructor fixes that.

The following line in the display function is missing a `this.` for `c`:

```js
pixels[int(this.posX) + int(this.posY) * width] = c; // should be this.c
```

You're also not looping through all of the particles, which may be a concious decision but it looks pretty awesome when you do:

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    particles[i].update();
    particles[i].display();
    particles[i].wrap();
  }
```

When dealing with pixels you have to consider that there are 4 elements in the pixels array which represent the R, G, B, A values in order of each pixel. So to get the index of a given X and Y:

```
  let index =  (int(this.posX) + int(this.posY) * width) * 4;
```

And lastly, you'll probably need to set `pixelDensity(1)` so that it covers the whole screen, more information can be found in [the p5.js docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixelDensity).

I've used es6 classes rather than functions, but the premise is the same:

```js
var particles = [];
let particle = [];
const num = 100;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 400);
  pixelDensity(1);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  setParticles();
}

function draw() {
  frameRate(30);
  let alpha = map(height, 0, width, 5, 35);
  fill(0, alpha);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  loadPixels();
  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    particles[i].update();
    particles[i].display();
    particles[i].wrap();
  }
  updatePixels();
}

function setParticles() {
  particles = new Array(10000);
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    var x = random(width);
    var y = random(height);
    var adj = map(y, 0, height, 255, 0);
    let c = color(60, adj, 255);
    particles[i] = new Particle(x, y, c);
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  setParticles();
}

class Particle {
  constructor(xln, yln, cln) {
    this.posX = xln;
    this.posY = yln;
    this.c = cln;
    this.incr = 0;
  }

  update() {
    this.incr += 0.008;
    this.theta = noise(this.posX * 0.006, this.posY * 0.008, this.incr) * TWO_PI;
    this.posX += 2 * tan(this.theta);
    this.posY += 2 * sin(this.theta);
  }

  display() {
    if (
      this.posX > 0 &&
      this.posX < width &&
      this.posY > 0 &&
      this.posY < height
    ) {
      let index =  (int(this.posX) + int(this.posY) * width) * 4;
      pixels[index] = this.c; 
      pixels[index+1] = this.c; 
      pixels[index+2] = this.c; 
      pixels[index+3] = this.c; 
    }
  }

  wrap() {
    if (this.posX < 0) this.posX = width;
    if (this.posX > width) this.posX = 0;
    if (this.posY < 0) this.posY = height;
    if (this.posY > height) this.posY = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's a link to the [p5.js editor sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/codeheir/sketches/7mdoTcHwc).